# Apache Flink: The file STDOUT is not available on the TaskExecutor

Tags: scala, docker, logging, apache-flink

I started flink with the following docker-compose.yml from the official flink repository. I only added the connection to the external hadoop network.

```
version: "2.1"

networks:
  hadoop:
    external:
      name: flink_hadoop

services:
  jobmanager:
    image: flink:1.7.1-hadoop27-scala_2.11
    container_name: flink-jobmanager
    domainname: hadoop
    networks:
      - hadoop
    expose:
      - "6123"
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    command: jobmanager
    environment:
      - JOB_MANAGER_RPC_ADDRESS=jobmanager

  taskmanager:
    image: flink:1.7.1-hadoop27-scala_2.11
    container_name: flink-taskmanager
    domainname: hadoop
    networks:
      - hadoop
    expose:
      - "6121"
      - "6122"
    depends_on:
      - jobmanager
    command: taskmanager
    links:
      - "jobmanager:jobmanager"
    environment:
      - JOB_MANAGER_RPC_ADDRESS=jobmanager
```

After this everything runs and I can access the WebUI.

Then I packaged the following job.

```
import org.apache.flink.api.scala._
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import stoff.schnaps.pojo.ActorMovie

object HdfsJob {
  private lazy val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass)

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    // set up the batch execution environment
    val env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    val actorMovies = env
      .readCsvFile[ActorMovie](
      "hdfs://namenode:8020/source-data/test.tsv",
      "\r\n",
      "\t",
      includedFields = Array(2,3,5),
      pojoFields = Array("actor",
                         "film",
                         "character"))

    actorMovies.print

    // execute program
    env.execute("Flink Batch Scala API Skeleton")
  }
}
```

Which just reads a tsv file from hdfs into a DataSet of pojos and prints this. When I let this run local everything works fine. But when I upload the .jar and let it run on the cluster, the jobmanager logs the following exceptions:

`java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: The file STDOUT is not available on the TaskExecutor.`

`java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: The file LOG is not available on the TaskExecutor.`

And obviously the taskmanager contains no logs, what the current problem is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When running Flink on Docker, the `docker-entrypoint.sh` script will start the Flink processes (`TaskExecutor` and `JobMaster`) [in the foreground](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-container/docker/docker-entrypoint.sh#L37). This has the effect that Flink will neither redirect its `STDOUT` into a file nor will it log into a file. Instead, Flink will also log to `STDOUT`. That way, you can view the logs and the stdout output of your docker containers via `docker logs`.

If you want to change this behaviour, it should be sufficient to alter `docker-entrypoint.sh` and pass `start` instead of `start-foreground`:

```
if [ "${CMD}" == "${TASK_MANAGER}" ]; then
    $FLINK_HOME/bin/taskmanager.sh start "$@"
else
    $FLINK_HOME/bin/standalone-job.sh start "$@"
fi

sleep 1
exec /bin/bash -c "tail -f $FLINK_HOME/log/*.log"
```

#### Update

When using Flink's `DataSet` API, calling the method `DataSet::print` will actually retrieve the respective `DataSet` from the cluster back to the client where it is printed to STDOUT. Due to the retrieval, this method only works if the job has been submitted by Flink's CLI client via `bin/flink run <job.jar>`. This behavior is different from the `DataStream::print` method which prints the `DataStream` on the `TaskManagers` where the program is executed.

If you want to print the `DataSet` results on the `TaskManager`, one needs to call `DataSet::printOnTaskManager` instead of `print`.

Comment: I understand so far.. but I also get no output with `docker logs`.. The logs just shows a wall of exceptions..

Comment: What exceptions do you see? Are they originating from the web UI which cannot find the log and stdout files? If so, your results must be buried somewhere under these messages.

Comment: When I start flink and click on Task Managers, select a task and the click on logs I receive the following log output. http://snippi.com/s/1dp5hjt The first exception that the name or service is not known repeats all 12 seconds..

Comment: Is this happening with my proposed change?

Comment: When I change it to start then I can see the logs. What sense does this have? When I use the default with standalone-start then I can't either see the logs in the WebUI nor in docker logs. Which part do I misunderstand? I thought the images are always ready-to-use.. Or is flink just not that compatible with docker?

Comment: When using the default, you should be able to see the logs via `docker logs` or when using `docker-compose up` they should be printed to stdout. At least this worked for me locally. The logs not being accessible through the web UI is a known limitation when using the vanilla Flink Docker files atm and should be improved in the future.

Comment: I understand.. So when I use docker logs, I can see logs but not the stdout. So when I use the print method on a DataSet I don't get this output. How can I get this output else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186219/discussion-between-daniel-eisenreich-and-till-rohrmann).

Comment: @DanielEisenreich I've updated my answer with the solution.